# Managing alignment for JSON display with react-json-tree

Tags: reactjs, json, rendering

I'm using react-json-tree library to display a JSON. With the following theme:

```
  const myTheme = {
    base00: '#272822',
    base01: '#383830',
    base02: '#49483e',
    base03: '#75715e',
    base04: '#a59f85',
    alignItems: 'left',
    nestedNodeLabel: ({ style }, keyPath, nodeType, expanded) => ({
        style: {
            textTransform: expanded ? 'uppercase' : style.textTransform,
            fontSize:'12px'
        },
      }),
    nestedKeyLabel: {
        fontSize:'12px',
    },
    value: {
        fontSize:'12px'
    },
  };
```

the rendering looks like this:
[image]

Despite I have 'align: left', the key/value are centered. How can I left align them properly (under the item arrow)? Is there also a way to replace (in the rendered JSON):

```
name: <name>
value: <value>
```

with:

```
<name>: <value>
```

Last, what is the best way to find a list of all the configuration parameters of "theme" (there seems to be many ...)

Many thanks for your help.
C

Answer (score 0):

After looking around further, I found out that this would do the trick:

```
labelRenderer={([key]) => <em align="left" padding-left="10%">{key}</em>
```

In :

```
     <JSONTree 
      labelRenderer={([key]) => <em align="left" padding-left="10%">{key}</em>}
      valueRenderer={(raw) => <em>{raw}</em>} 
      expandActionRoot='true'
      hideRoot='true'
      getItemString={() => {}}
      data={data} theme={theme}/>
```

Christian